# Unable to deploy django app on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, foreman

Trying to deploy app on heroku.

Followed the link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django step by step.

Installed django-toolbelt started in virtual env

Cant understand the reason for the faliure.

00:15:19 web.1  | started with pid 5336

00:15:20 web.1  | 2013-08-21 00:15:20 [5339] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.5

00:15:20 web.1  | `2013-08-21 00:15:20 [5339] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (5339)`

00:15:20 web.1  | 2013-08-21 00:15:20 [5339] [INFO] Using worker: sync

00:15:20 web.1  | 2013-08-21 00:15:20 [5342] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5342

00:15:20 web.1  | 2013-08-21 00:15:20 [5342] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5342)

00:15:20 web.1  | 2013-08-21 00:15:20 [5339] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

00:15:20 web.1  | 2013-08-21 00:15:20 [5339] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

00:15:20 web.1  | exited with code 3

00:15:20 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes

SIGTERM received

Comment: Use this for more info: "--debug --log-level debug"

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your log shows

```
Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

Which looks like gunicorn is running on port 5000. Heroku apps typically run on a different port number based on the `$PORT` environment variable. I am supposing that Heroku has started your app (on port 5000) and then checks if it is up on port 12345 (or whatever is in `$PORT`).

Try updating your `Procfile` to

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

gunicorn versions [>= 0.16.0](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/18.0/news.html#id9) should listen on `$PORT` automatically.